# Anti debugging - Preventing memory dumps

Tags: debugging, memory, dump

I am trying to implement some basic anti debugging functionality in my application. One area that I wanted to focus on in particular, is attempting to prevent people from easily taking a usable memory dump from my application. I read the article at:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/AntiReverseEngineering.aspx

and that gave me a lot of tips for how to detect if a debugger is present, as well as some information on how I might prevent memory dumps. But the author notes that one should be careful about using these techniques, such as removing the executable header in memory. He mentions that there might be times when the OS or other programs may want to use this information, but I cannot see for what purpose.

Has anyone got some other tips as to how I could stop reverse engineers from dumping my program?

I am on Windows.

Kind regards,

Philip Bennefall

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no reasonable way to prevent someone from capturing a memory dump of your process. For example, I could attach a kernel debugger to the system, break all execution, and extract your process' dump from the debugger. Therefore, I would focus on making analysis more difficult.

Here are some ideas:

- Obfuscate and encrypt your executable code. Decrypt in-memory only, and do not keep decrypted code around for longer than you need it.
- Do not store sensitive information in memory for longer than necessary. Use `RtlZeroMemory` or a similar API to clear out buffers that you are no longer using. This also applies to the stack (local variables and parameters).